# How to scale the font size in a carousel of cards with constant card width?

Tags: css, react-native

I am working on a React Native app, where I have a carousel of cards like below. The width of the cards is constant. The text inside the card occupies 100 percent of the card width. The font size is also constant. In iOS, some of the devices are overflowing the text outside the card. So, how to scale the fonts based on card height and width.

I believe, I cannot scale based on the device height and width as the text is inside the card, and the card height and width are constant.

[image]

To make it much clearer, below is how a single card looks like in a carousel. There are different columns in each card and text occupies full length of the column

[image]

Comment: Card width, height are constant.
so let font size constant too.

Comment: Can you please add the code of the Card Component? Maybe some styling issue.

Comment: There is a lot of code, I believe I will add more complexity if I add it here. 

But the font sizes are constant as well. But in iOS, different screen sizes are rendering it with different font sizes, I believe it is something to do with pixel density

Comment: give overflow: 'hidden' to the cardview

Comment: I cannot hide content, it should be displayed at all times

Comment: what is your expected?